# How to add css box-shadow using .style JavaScript property

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got the following JavaScript snippet:

```
document.getElementById("imgA").style.box-shadow = "0 0 5px #999999";
```

The hyphen in `box-shadow` is causing the JavaScript engine to throw an invalid assignment exception (in Firefox). Doing `"box-shadow"` or `'box-shadow'` doesn't work. Is there a good way around this without using jquery's `.css()` method?

Comment: If the CSS property name is hyphenated, replace the hyphen with the capital letter. Thus for eg: `text-align` will become `textAlign`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `style["boxShadow"]` or `style.boxShadow`.

```js
document.getElementById("foo").style["boxShadow"] = "0 0 5px #999999";
```

```html
<div id="foo">12123123</div>
```

Comment: `.style["box-shadow"]` is possible as well.

Answer (score 5):

CSS properties with a `-` are represented in `camelCase` in `Javascript` objects. So you dont need a hyphen `-` just write `boxShadow`

```js
document.getElementById("shadow").style["boxShadow"] = "0 0 5px #999999";
```

```html
<div id="shadow">Tushar </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `boxShadow`

```
document.getElementById("imgA").style.boxShadow = "0 0 5px #999999";
```

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementById('redbox').style.boxShadow = "0 0 3px #000";`

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
document.getElementById("demo").style.boxShadow = "0 0 5px #999999";
```